# Why did a moderator destroy the comments to this question and thereby render the answers vastly less useful?

Tags: discussion, moderation

I provided a number of comments to the question [How to use `getc()` instead of `fgets()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931567/how-to-use-getc-instead-of-fgets-in-my-program), along with some other people also providing comments, which were intended to guide the person asking towards the answer.  I later provided an answer, but the commentary within the answer was minimal because the relevant information explaining/justifying its contents was mostly in the comments to the question.  I didn't have the time/energy to transfer the commentary into my answer.

Overnight (my time), somebody got *all* the comments removed, depriving Stack Overflow of important material.  Yes, comments are supposed to be 'ephemeral' — and these ones surely were — but you're not supposed to destroy valuable material, either.  And these comments were of some value, and the answers were written on the assumption that the discussion and guidance in the comments would continue to exist.

They don't; they've been lost, presumably forever.

How can we prevent such wanton vandalism of valuable material from recurring?  Yes, ideally I'd have enough time to beautifully transfer the relevant comments into an answer and edit and craft them into cogent text.  Wake up!  That isn't the world I live in, and I doubt if it is the world you live in either.

It must have involved moderator intervention; I didn't remove my comments, and I somehow don't suppose that the other commenting parties all removed theirs.

Please can we work out how to prevent over-enthusiastic moderatorial intervention in comment clean-up?

At the very least, if someone had contacted me saying "these comments need to be cleaned up; please transfer any relevant material into your answer" (e.g. with an `@JonathanLeffler` comment), I would have done the transfer when I had time, for all it was unnecessary busy-work.  As it is, 90% of the educational value of the Q&A has gone.

Comment: Welcome to our wonderful world of "second-class citizen", "ephemeral" comments. I'm afraid that's by design.

Comment: Stack Exchange isn't a forum. You could've chatted about the issue.

Comment: @nhgrif: no, I couldn't.  1-rep users can't chat — unless they've fixed that bug and not told me about it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: There will be a major loss to the site's value if all comment chains get removed; it will drastically reduce the quality of site.  This was, IMNSHO, a major mistake by the relevant moderator.

Comment: @Jonathan, I'm also not a fan of outright removal of comments, but that's the way things work here, and that will be pretty difficult to change I believe.

Comment: So what you're saying is, you didn't have enough time transfer the comments to an answer; but you did have enough time to complain on meta about it? Ok then.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I've not seen a clean-sweep of 15-20 comments before. It seems to be a new moderation policy if that's going to happen on a routine basis. It didn't occur to me that important, constructive comments would be zapped like that. Trivial comments — yes, no problem. I flag them quite a lot. But substantive commentary seeking and giving guidance — no, I've not seen that radical a cleanup done before. And because I didn't expect it, and because my answer only clarified what was in the commentary, I didn't know it was going to be necessary, or I might have worked on it last night.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - don't roll back again, otherwise we'll lock the post.

Comment: This is extremely common on other StackExchanges. I'm not surprised at all if it's becoming more common on StackOverflow. Just avoid putting content you think is valuable enough to be preserved in comments. Or at least pull them over to chat if you're having a lot of back and forth with the OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> At the very least, if someone had contacted me saying "these comments
>   need to be cleaned up; please transfer any relevant material into your
>   answer".

That would indeed be constructive. Everything is not lost, though.

Moderators have access to the full comment thread history, including modified and deleted comments. If you flag the question for moderator attention and ask them to send you the content of your deleted comments, I'm quite sure they would oblige.

You could then paste that content back into your answer, and that information would become available to the rest of us again.

Comment: I suppose that's worth a try.  On a one-off basis, it isn't a problem.  But it isn't going to be a sensible way of doing business for many questions.

Comment: I did post a request to the moderators (a moderator flag), but I haven't heard back. In the office, I found the browser tab in which I'd created the answer still open at the question, so I still had a copy of the comments.  I've updated my answer to include an edited version of the comment trail.

Answer (score 19):

Comments should not contain answers.

If you add a comment (or several comments) which ultimately turn out to contain useful information then you should either:

1. Edit that information into the post.
2. Post an answer containing your information.

Comments are meant to be transitory and can be deleted at any time.

If we see that they contain useful information we may leave a comment before deleting, but that's not always possible - especially when a comment thread gets very long and diverges from the point.

Answer (score 14):

There were a few parts to this.

1. You posted a few comments that were extremely long and hard to read as comments:

[image: Comment 1]
And:
[image: Comment 2]
And:
[image]

That in of itself is not only discouraged, but actively detrimental to other users who may want an answer to the question. If your answer is there; how would you expect anyone to reasonably parse that comment for the answer? at best they'd have to copy and paste the comment, reformat the code; and hope it works.

2. There were more than 20 comments posted; most of which were dialog.  Your 'answer' was interspersed among these; but it seemed more like a back and forth than it did an answer.
3. The question was custom flagged for another reason that I won't get into. These three things together contributed to your comments being deleted.

Comment: I agree with what you said. But I don't see why anyone would flag them or a mod would act upon them. Even if they are not of much use in general but of use for *some* (at least OP), considering there's no malice there but helpful useful info (however little use it may have).

Comment: I think there might even be a simpler explanation for the removal of the comments in that one half of the conversation was deleted by the poster themselves. Moderators can only undelete comments that we deleted. When half of the conversation is gone, the other half makes a lot less sense and looks bizarre in a comment string. We typically will get flagged to clean up stuff like this, so when the question itself was flagged, I'm guessing that's what happened. Moderators didn't remove half of this conversation, the user behind it did.

Comment: @BradLarson Excellent point!

Comment: George and Brad pretty much hit the nail on the head here. The only thing I have to add is that the state the question was in when I viewed it initially was pretty bad, most of the context to the answers and comments had been removed from the question, most of the comments were obsolete and/or not constructive to begin with. Your conversation with the OP seemed to have run its course based on the last (and at that point already deleted) comment from the OP and was largely tangential to the actual question itself.